# how to run custom block validation logic when importing a block?

Tags: extrinsic, block, aura

I am trying to execute some logic whenever a block is received, specifically i want to create custom transactions validation of a received block.

can someone provide a clear example (simple code) on how to provide extra verification of a received block in aura?

ps: i noticed that aura use grandpa when it creates its BlockImport, i assume this has something to with verifying the block if so why aura is using grandpa validation logic of having its own, and is there a way to simply extend it by plugging extra verification logic, if that is indeed the correct place for verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own [`BlockImport`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/4d29da2156d587a6b8e4efbe10e412efaedbbd4e/client/consensus/common/src/block_import.rs#L338):

```
struct BlockImport<I>(I);

impl<I: sc_consensus::BlockImport> sc_consensus::BlockImport for BlockImport<I> {
    type Error = I::Error;
    type Transaction = I::Transaction;

    async fn check_block(
        &mut self,
        block: BlockCheckParams<B>,
    ) -> Result<ImportResult, Self::Error> {
        self.0.check_block(block).await
    }

    async fn import_block(
        &mut self,
        block: BlockImportParams<B, Self::Transaction>,
        cache: HashMap<CacheKeyId, Vec<u8>>,
    ) -> Result<ImportResult, Self::Error> {
        if let Some(transactions) = &block.body {
             // Do whatever check you need with the transactions
        }

        self.0.import_block(block, cache).await
    }
}
```

Then in your service you stack `BlockImport(AuraBlockImport(GrandpaBlockImport(Client)))` and each external block will be checked with your custom logic.

Comment: when i put my CustomBlockImport in [here](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/6c701fa6109693a955bb1fa317d8b724634e0fa7/node/src/service.rs#L117) , the code compiles and it executes with no errors by it does not execute mu custom BlockImport (i put prinln!() everywhere just to be sure and nothing was printed),  where is the right place to place it to work ?

Comment: Be aware that this code is only called when the block is imported from the network. If you are just running with `--dev` for example, you also need to the block import here: https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/6c701fa6109693a955bb1fa317d8b724634e0fa7/node/src/service.rs#L262.
However, I think you don't need to check the extrinsic on your local node after building the block?

Comment: i guess im going to write another BlockImport and use it in there, however i dont understand what are those two functions (new_partial and new_full) and why in the first we provide new_partial and in the second we dont, and which BlockImport does it gets executed, is it the first or the second?

Comment: These are different code paths, one is called when a block is being produced by the local node and the other is when importing a block from the network into the local node.

Comment: It is initialized here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/f2bc08a3071a91b71fec63cf2b22c707411cec0e/bin/node-template/node/src/service.rs#L145